# How to manage dependencies in Java

Tags: java, reference, hadoop

I'm totally new to Java and I'm trying to build a Hadoop MapReduce program. I added `/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar` and everything builds fine. When I export the project as a `jar file` and try to run it, it gives me a `ClassNotFoundException` when I run it because it doesn't not where to find the `hadoop-core.jar`. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to add a reference to the required resource into the manifest file of the main Jar.  The references are relative, so the most common practice is to ensure the main and dependent Jars are in the same directory.

If deploying as an applet the Jar can be referenced in the archive attribute of the applet element.

If deploying using Java Web Start, the Jar can be referenced in the JNLP launch file.

---

Edit 1:  Example of manifest presuming the dependent Jar is in the 'hadoop' sub-directory of the directory where the app. is located.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Main-Class: org.pscode.wigglyworms.WigglyWorms
Class-Path: hadoop/hadoop-core.jar
Implementation-Title: Wiggly Worms
Implementation-Version: 11.03.13
Implementation-Vendor: PSCode - Andrew Thompson
Implementation-Vendor-Id: org.pscode
Created-By: 1.6.0-b105 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
```

Note that a manifest file should end with a single blank line (which is difficult to represent even using the 'pre-formatted' mode for code).  For that reason I would strongly recommend you leave the creation of the manifest to a tool that knows how to write them.  My choice is the Ant build tool.

For further details, see [Adding Classes to the JAR File's Classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) section of the 'Packaging Programs in JAR Files' lesson of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the manifest file contents would look like?

Answer (score 1):

This should help [The java application launcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html)

Answer (score 1):

The jar command won't include the `hadoop-core.jar` inside the jar you built. So at runtime (i.e. when you execute the `java` command) you need to specify hadoop on your classpath. Check out the `-cp` or `-classpath` command line argument. Basically it will look something like this:

```
java -cp myjar.jar;hadoop-core.jar package.Main
```

Comment: Given my `main` method is in the class `WordCount2` and my module is `wordcount2.jar` entering this: `sudo java -cp wordcount2.jar;/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar package.Main` just prints out the help screen and a statement at the end: `bash: /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar: Permission denied`
`

Comment: Ah right, I should have mentioned the `package.Main` should basically be the fully qualified path to `WordCount2`, (the package of `WordCount2` is specified by the package keyword up the top of WordCount2's java file). So all up your command should be `java -cp wordcount2.jar;/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar wordcount2spackage.WordCount2`. As for the `Permission denied` it's hard for me to say. Double check the path and file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

When you run the jar file you built, it needs to have a CLASSPATH environmental variable which contains the full path to /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar  it might look something like this

```
set CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-core.jar
export CLASSPATH
```

Other techniques exist, but the basic idea is that your JVM knows where the classes are you built, but it has no idea where to look for the hadoop-core classes.

Comment: I'm a total noob. Where do I setup an environment variable like that?

Comment: Even Sun, some years ago, was recommending against throwing everything into the CLASSPATH environmental variable.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use File -> Export -> Runnable jar, which provide several options for doing what you need.